# MongoDB generate UUID with dashes

Tags: mongodb, uuid

I need to add random UUID with dashes to my column GUID. 
How I should write my sql script, I was using `GUID = MD5(UUID());` but it generates UUID without dashes, what would be solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `MD5(UUID())`, it no longer is a `UUID`, and the "guaranteed unique" property is also lost. Don't do that.

That said, a `UUID` is a 128 bits number. It doesn't have dashes. Some representations do, but that's a display issue.